# add_action with a class method is causing fatal errors

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I wasn't sure if this was a PHP issue (suited for StackOverflow) or a WordPress issue (suited for StackExchange), however since my issue **appears** to be with the `add_action()` function, I have placed the question here.

Here's some simplified code which causes the same issue (to avoid re-posting my couple-hundred line plugin):

```
<?php
$class = new MyClass();
add_action('init', array($class, 'init'));

class MyClass {
    public static function init() {
        $this->core();
    }
    public static function core() {
        echo "I never get this far...";
    }
}
?>
```

I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Using $this when not in object context in **/home/coupon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/test.php** on line **7**

If my `add_action()` call were instead:

```
add_action('init', 'MyClass::init');
```

Then I would understand this error (since the function was called statically and there is no instance of DEMenu for `$this` to point to), however I don't understand why this is happening since I used an array and passed an instance of the class.

My specific issue is actually related to this problem. I created a custom Walker class then used the `wp_nav_menu_args` filter to pass my custom Walker. I get this error in `class-wp-walker.php` on line **185**. The line in particular is:

```
$id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
```

Any ideas?

EDIT -

`test.php` is now functioning properly, but the original issue is not solved... As such here's my plugin's index.php file (simplified):

```
$DEMenu = new DEMenu();

class DEMenu {

    function DEMenu() {
        if (is_admin()) {
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'admin'));
        } else {
            add_action('init', array(&$this, 'core'));
        }
    }

    public function admin() {
        /* Not important */
    }

    public function core() {
        add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', array(&$this, 'add_walker'));
    }

    public function add_walker( $args ) {
        $args['walker'] = 'DEMenu_Walker';
        return $args;
    }

}

class DEMenu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function __construct() {
        die("We made it to the constructor!");
    }

}
```

As mentioned above, I am getting the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Using $this when not in object context in **/home/coupon/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php** on line **185**

Since the above `test.php` was failing and since the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class never has this error normally (not until I added my plugin) I figured the issue was with the one of my `add_action()` or `add_filter()` calls. However since it is still failing I'm not entirely sure where the issue is...

FINAL EDIT -

Carefully re-reading the `walk_nav_menu_tree()` function, I have found the issue with my walker class...

```
function walk_nav_menu_tree( $items, $depth, $r ) {
        $walker = ( empty($r->walker) ) ? new Walker_Nav_Menu : $r->walker;
        $args = array( $items, $depth, $r );

        return call_user_func_array( array(&$walker, 'walk'), $args );
}
```

Since `$walker` is being set to `$r->walker` it is a string, not an instance of a class. Therefore the class method is called statically instead of via an instance of the class. Instead of:

```
$args['walker'] = 'DEMenu_Walker';
```

I should have:

```
$args['walker'] = new DEMenu_Walker();
```

---

**Task**: Call a class method as a hook for a WordPress plugin so that the `$this` variable is not broken

Comment: +1 for editing your question with the insight about passing a new instance of your Walker class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$class = new MyClass();

class MyClass {
    public function MyClass() {
       add_action('init', array($this, 'core'));
    }
    public static function core() {
        echo "I never get to here";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This gave me a new error: `Fatal error: Constructor MyClass::MyClass() cannot be static in /home/coupon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/test.php on line 11`

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. Instead of `public static function MyClass(){` it should be just `function MyClass(){`. That's actually probably what problem was all along. I kept using `public static function` instead of `public function`.

Comment: Now `test.php` is functioning properly, but the Walker class is still messed up... I'm going to edit my original question to include my simplified plugin class.

Comment: Issue with the Walker actually had nothing to do with this issue (although this issue was still causing bugs here and there, and you did answer the question very well). I solved the walker issue and included the answer in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$class = new MyClass();
add_action('init', array($class, 'init'));
```

That is correct! You have the PHP-Error, you must Add a Constructor to your Class with returnin the "Instance/Object" like:

```
class MyClass {
    function __construct() {
        return $this;
    }

    /* The other Methods... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are to deal with static class and methods

```
class Kc_Class{

  static function init(){

      add_action('some_hook',array(__CLASS__,'my_static_method'));

  }    
  static function my_static_method(){

    ...
  }
}
```

Then make a call to  your init method

```
Kc_Class::init();
```